# Javascript one line if else shorthand confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var type = ''; // type is from somewhere
if(type == 'a'){
type = 1;
}else{
type = 2;
}
```

How to simplify above if else statement using JS shorthand?

Comment: Well, you could shorten that to `var type = 2;`

Comment: @David type is from somewhere..

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you mean by "JS shorthand", but maybe you're looking for the [ternary conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)?

```
type = (type == 'a') ? 1 : 2;
```

Comment: is this it! but I tried without the bracket it worked too, is the bracket mandatory?

Comment: @JamesLemon: The parentheses aren't always necessary, it depends on the operator precedence.  Given the number of operators in the statement, I personally think this makes it more clear.

Comment: what else can the operator can be except `==` ?

Comment: @JamesLemon: The condition can be anything which produces a boolean value.  It doesn't even have to be a comparison, as long as it results in a true or false.

Comment: I see, like it can be `!=`.. but isn't true or false only have 3 comparison operators? the `!=', `==` and `===` ?

Comment: @JamesLemon: Or `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, or a function which results in a boolean, etc.  Anything which can be used in the body of an `if` statement.

Comment: @JamesLemon: In fact, it can be any **expression**, just like with the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operator, also called the conditional operator, inline if (iif), or ternary if. In your example, this would look like the following:

```
type = type == 'a' ? 1 : 2;
```

More info on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:

Answer (score 0):

You have more options than just a ternary, especially considering that `1` is not *falsy*

```
type = {'a': 1}[type] || 2;
```

Comment: More complicated than ternary for no real benefit.

Comment: @Saposhiente the benefits start coming when you have a large number of options, i.e. this answer is a very simple dictionary lookup with default value.